# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open package.json

Tags: javascript, nodejs, studio

`Tengo un problema con el npm install,Me salió esto y si me dan una mano se los agradezco

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Persona\Desktop/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Persona\Desktop\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Hice un npm doctor y salió ésto:

```
 npm doctor
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
Check                    Value   Recommendation/Notes
npm ping                 ok
npm -v                   ok      current: v8.19.2, latest: v8.19.2
node -v                  not ok  Use node v16.17.0 (current: v16.16.0)
npm config get registry  ok      using default registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/)
which git                ok      C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.EXE
Verify cache contents    ok      verified 14 tarballs
npm ERR! Some problems found. See above for recommendations.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

ahora con el nuevo npm install me salió esto:

```
$ npm install
up to date in 3s
```

29 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

Comment: Hello Friend, your Post has a problem and is written in a different Language than the expected on the Site; I recommend that you translate it into Spanish.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Y cuál es el problema con `npm install`? Añádelo, por favor

Comment: La información adicional va en la pregunta, no en los comentarios, presiona [edit] para agregar información a tu pregunta.

Comment: por favor edita tu pregunta y añádenos ese detalle.

Comment: listo ahí puse lo que me salió cuando hice el npm install

Comment: No destruyas la pregunta. Añade cosas, no reemplaces. Y la respuesta es que debes correr npm install en la carpeta raíz del proyecto, donde esté el package.json del proyecto

Comment: okey lo hice pero no entiendo que hice ahora ,no me queda como antes

Comment: @TobiasVega el error que te esta mostrando al principio, es porque para ejecutar el comando ``npm install`` tenes que estar parado en una carpeta donde exista un archivo llamado ``package.json``, asegurate eso leyendo la ruta del terminal donde tiras el comando, y si no funciona, agrega el archivo ``package.json`` a tu pregunta

Comment: Siempre que quieras ejecutar **npm install** en un proyecto que descargas por ejemplo o que clonas de GitHub tienes que hacerlo dentro de la carpeta donde se encuentra el `package.json`. **npm install** va a ejecutar las dependencias que se encuentren en el `package.json` y las va a instalar para que el proyecto funcione correctamente, para que se te haga mas fácil busca la carpeta donde esta el  `package.json` le das click derecho y en abrir terminal

Comment: `not ok  Use node v16.17.0 (current: v16.16.0)` -> que dice que actualices tu NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que inicializar NPM para generar el archivo package.json que utiliza para poder instalar en él los paquetes.

> npm init

Answer (score 0):

Tuve ese problema y basta con reinstalar npm:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```